# Finding minimum value in a sorted array that was rotated, using concurrency

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

This is an interview question.

In the first part I was asked for finding a minimum value in a sorted array that was rotated (for example, the sorted array `[1,2,3,4]` was rotated to `[3,4,1,2]` ).
The algorithm for doing it can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-minimum-element-in-a-sorted-and-rotated-array/).

Then I was asked for improving the algorithm by using parallel computing. That was my suggestion:

1. Assuming we can run `k` threads in parallel, divide the array into `k` equal size sub arrays (besides perhaps the last part).
2. Perform the algorithm above on each of the `k` sub arrays.
3. Return the minimum value from the `k` algorithm runnings.

The interviewer said the algorithm run time isn’t good enough. Do you know a better solution?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I have some reasoning. The runtime of your algorithm is `O(log n)`. If you divide the array into `k` parts, you will get `O(log (n/k))` and you need to find the minimum element out of the `k` results. With a linear search, this will give you `O(log(n/k) + k) = O(log n - log k + k)`. Since `log k` is usually smaller than `k`, you have most likely made it worse. In fact, almost all threads (except one) will immediately return the first element as their minimum and go to sleep. The answer might just be to leave it single-threaded.

Comment: @NicoSchertler your analysis is assuming a solution must use the results of all k threads. See my answer that shows why that is not required and how to improve on O(n) time.

Answer (score -1):

Let's suppose you have *n+1* hardware threads. You can have *n* threads process the array, each thread "responsible" for 1 entry and completing in O(1) time, and the remaining thread waiting for the result. For efficiency, the threads should be started beforehand and initialized with an index variable (*i*), otherwise the initialization itself will be O(n) time. The process in each thread could be:

```
if arr[i] > arr[(i + 1) mod n]
  SharedMemResult = arr[(i + 1) mod n]
```

This is obviously O(1) time, and all the "master" thread had to do is read `SharedMemResult` till it changes (of course this needs to be initialized to some extreme value, and memory barriers should be used to prevent reordering...).

Using the same concept, we could utilize *m* threads where each thread finds the minimum in the range (n*i/m) -> (n*(i+1)/m - 1) in O(log(n/m)) time, and then verifies this to be the true minimum (only relevant of the first item on the range is the minimum, but this will be the case for most ranges).

The result is an algorithm that solves the problem in O(log(n/m)) time.

Comment: I didn't understand completely your algorithm, but I still think there is a problem with it: you forgot that we have to initialize those m threads, which means that this algorithm runs in O(log(n/m) + m) =  O(logn - logm + m) , and that isn't better than the single thread algorithm (just like @Nico Schertler wrote)

Comment: @John - I didn't forget that... In fact, I specifically said: "*the threads should be started beforehand and initialized with an index variable...*". This is like a thread pool you prepare once and use in each execution of the algorithm. What didn't you understand about the algorithm?